# lxc-ls doesn't list all containers

Tags: lxc

I am running a simple application container using the following command:

```
lxc-execute -n container_name -- sleep 100
```

For listing all containers we have `lxc-ls` command and for seeing active containers we have `lxc-ls --active` command. But both of them does not give any output. Whereas `lxc-info -n container_name` gives all the relevant information about the container. Can anybody sort out why this `lxc-ls` command not listing containers?

P.S. I am using ubuntu 14.04 and lxc 2.0.0.

Comment: I have this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using privileged containers, so you should use sudo with your lxc-ls commands:

```
sudo lxc-ls -f
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Can you see into this.

Comment: It looks like there was a problem with up gradation. So please dont upgrade to avoid any kind of errors.

Comment: Your comment does not say which upgrade u did, but I'm quite certain that to be able to list privileged containers, one only need to do "sudo lxc-ls -f", but if that does not work then u maybe have.problems somewhere else in the system,,e.g in the sudoers file etc.